# How can I autofill a form using htmlunit?

Tags: jsoup, htmlunit

I want to auto-fill and auto-submit all the textboxes in a site when the URL of the site is entered.Can anyone help me providing its code in jsoup or htmlunit or java?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example with HTMLUnit

```
public void submittingForm() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    // Get the first page
    HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://some_url");

    // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
    // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
    HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("myform");

    HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("submitbutton");
    HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("userid");

    // Change the value of the text field
    textField.setValueAttribute("root");

    // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
    HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

Comment: @LoveenaMathews can you give me the page url so I can check?

Comment: url:www.safesecurities.com.pk